# Is there any commercial stand mixer bigger than kitchenaids with bowl scraping paddle?

Tags: stand-mixer

the biggest kitchenaid with a bowl scraping paddle (called flex edge by them) is a 7 quart mixer. i would choose something bigger only if such paddle that also scrapes the side of the bowl when mixing was available. any knows if it exists?
thanks : )

Comment: Like this? [80qt mixer with scraper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h625k8r0nr4)

Comment: Here's the [Scraper attachment for Hobart 12qt](http://www.centralrestaurant.com/Primary-12-Qt-Bowl-Scraper---For-Hobart-HL120-Mixer-c83p29940.html?gclid=CjkKEQjwlIqdBRDy6JSK4Lmn1akBEiQAVa9dPWq_G4xAM7VeeCleXWhzjG3-iv9vSDQvFJfBSklmfV7w_wcB)

Comment: Here's the [Hobart 12qt mixer that goes with the above attachment](http://www.centralrestaurant.com/Hobart-HL-120-1-STD-Legacy-Tabletop-Stand-Mixer---12-Qt-FREE-KIT-c83p29601.html). Pretty sweet piece of machinery!

Comment: Bosch, Electrolux, Magic Mill, they use a different mixing technique than the Kitchen Aid. I like it better.

Comment: perfect now i now that bigger mixers than kitcheanaids do exist! but hobart isnt available in europe! in the future im definitely travelling to the us to get one! @Jolenealaska

Comment: different mixing technique? could you please give more info @Optionparty

Comment: The "Magic Mill"/"Electrolux" are the same machine, has a whisk, hook, and roller/scraper. A "Roller/Scraper" kneads dough without adding much air. The ElectroLux will handle 2kg, don't try that in a Kitchen Aid. 

Dough mixing is a little different in an ElectroLux 
Here is a link to help explane http://tinyurl.com/334jmk

Comment: And for people who don't like clicking obfuscated links : http://www.breadmachinedigest.com/reviews/stand-mixer-reviews/electrolux-magic-mill-dlx-mixer.php

Comment: The original 'bowl scraping' paddles for Kitchen Aid mixers *weren't* sold by Kitchen Aid ... they were from [New Metro Design](http://www.newmetrodesign.com/content/BeaterBlade.html).  If there's a mixer brand that you use, you might contact them to see if they can get New Metro interested in making blades for their mixers.  (I'm guessing Kitchen Aid and Hobart already did or found ways around it ... although isn't Kitchen Aid a spinoff from Hobart?).  Oddly, their 'which one do I need' graphic leaves out the 20qt Hobart and 7qt Cuisinart/Viking/Kenwood models.

Comment: @Joe Yes, Kitchen Aid is Hobart: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KitchenAid

Comment: thanks all for your help! looks like the hobart will be my next machine!

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment:

If you really are interested in the [12qt Hobart Mixer](http://www.centralrestaurant.com/Hobart-HL-120-1-STD-Legacy-Tabletop-Stand-Mixer---12-Qt-FREE-KIT-c83p29601.html) with the [Bowl Scraper Attachment](http://www.centralrestaurant.com/Primary-12-Qt-Bowl-Scraper---For-Hobart-HL120-Mixer-c83p29940.html?gclid=CjkKEQjwlIqdBRDy6JSK4Lmn1akBEiQAVa9dPWq_G4xAM7VeeCleXWhzjG3-iv9vSDQvFJfBSklmfV7w_wcB) I'm sure they'll work with you to sell you one. Here's the [contact information](http://www.hobartcorp.com/notices/) for their international sales department.

Take a good look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h625k8r0nr4), the way the 12qt functions is the same as this monster 80qt machine.